# Finding if a python datetime has no time information

Tags: python, datetime

I want to trap values that are like this (in which there is not 'time info' on the datetime):

```
datetime.datetime(2009, 4, 6, 0, 0)
```

Is there a better way to detect these values other than testing hour/minute/second?

```
if value.hour == 0 and value.minute == 0 and value.second == 0:
     # do stuff
```

Comment: Caution to future viewers that midnight is a valid datetime for which hour/minute/second/microsecond values will all be zero. In general one should use `datetime.date` to represent values with no time part.

Comment: Mark's answer is the most compact and correct solution and works in any version of Python. Please consider accepting it as the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### In Python 3.4 and earlier

The time method works here. Evaluates as boolean false if there's zero'd-out time info.

```
if not value.time():
    # do stuff
```

Comment: @jtschoonhoven What's the solution for Python 3.5+ then?

Comment: @HendrikWiese there's a more fundamental problem which is that there's no way to distinguish between a `datetime` for midnight and one with "missing" time info.

With that caveat I'd use @Mark's solution below.

Comment: @jtschoonhoven I'd call that a major design flaw... but that's just my opinion.

Comment: @HendrikWiese one should use the `date` object for representing dates with no time information. `datetime` is intended for time objects that have both.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on python3.9. Here's what I used to verify:

`date = datetime.fromisoformat("2022-05-25")
print(bool(date.time()))`

Answer (score 10):

For python 3.5 and above:

```
if value.hour == 0 and value.minute == 0 and value.second == 0 and value.microsecond == 0:
  # do stuff
```

For python lower than 3.5:

```
if not value.time():
  # do stuff
```

Explanation: the boolean evaluation of a `datetime.time` instance [was changed in python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#time-objects) :

> In boolean contexts, a time object is always considered to be true.
>
> Changed in version 3.5: Before Python 3.5, a time object was considered to be false if it represented midnight in UTC. This behavior was considered obscure and error-prone and has been removed in Python 3.5. See bpo-13936 for full details.

Answer (score 7):

I see nothing wrong with your method, but you could compare it to a 'zeroed' time object.

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime(2009, 4, 6, 0, 0)
dt.time() == datetime.time()
```

Comment: As [all arguments are optional](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#time-objects) and default to 0 it can be just `datetime.time()` instead of `datetime.time(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could chain comparisons to make the code more concise:

```
if dt.hour == dt.minute == dt.second == 0:
    # do stuff
```

Alternatively, you can compare the time part of the datetime to [`time.min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.min), i.e. `'00:00:00'`:

```
from datetime import time

if dt.time() == time.min:
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option:

```
if not (value.hour or value.minute or value.second):
    # do stuff
```

Comment: Even if both your alternative and 'if not value.hour and not value.minute and not value.second' do the same, I find the latter expresses the intended behavior more clearly.

Answer (score -1):

When you convert datetime to string you get the following results:

```
from datetime import datetime

str(datetime(2023, 4, 27, 17, 30, 0)) 
# 2023-04-27 17:30:00

str(datetime(2023, 4, 27, 17, 30, 0, 55))
# 2023-04-27 17:30:00.000055

str(datetime(2023, 4, 27, 0, 0, 0, 55))
# 2023-04-27 00:00:00.000055

str(datetime(2023, 4, 27))
# 2023-04-27 00:00:00
```

Therefore, you can evaluate like this:

```
if str(value).endswith("00:00:00"):
    # do stuff
```

Works for any version of python.