# How to differentiate between a dateutil parsed date and a datetime with 0 for all time values

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, python-dateutil

As far as I can tell there is no way to distinguish the difference between these two date strings ('2020-10-07', '2020-10-07T00:00:00') once they are parsed by dateutil. I really would like to be able to tell the difference between a standalone date and a date with a timestamp of zero.

```
import dateutil.parser
import datetime

date_str = '2020-10-07'
time_str = '2020-10-07T00:00:00'

s = dateutil.parser.parse(date_str)
e = dateutil.parser.parse(time_str)
```

The ultimate goal is to set the time to the beginning of the day in the end of the day when it is a standalone date but leave the date alone when there is a time included. Get close with something like this but it still can't differentiate from this one case. If do you know of any good solution to this that would be really helpful.

```
if s == e and s.time() == datetime.time.min:
    e = datetime.datetime.combine(e, datetime.time.max)
```

Post is somewhat useful but it's outdated and I'm not even sure that it would work for my use case. [Finding if a python datetime has no time information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423673/finding-if-a-python-datetime-has-no-time-information/1423736)

Comment: why don't you just analyse the string? e.g. if it parses to datetime with a specific directive? not sure why you *have* to use `dateutil` here in the first place; those ISO format strings parse nicely with standard lib's `fromisoformat`.

Comment: Main reason I don't want to use pure string parsing is I want to solution it's a little bit less fragile and more flexible than that. The reason dateutil is needed is really for backwards compatibility So that any dates aren't strict iso format don't stop working once this update is made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function which uses a simple try/except to test if the input can be parsed to a date (i.e. has *no* time information) or a datetime object (i.e. *has* time information). If the input format is different from ISO format, you could also implement specific [strptime directives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

```
from datetime import date, time, datetime

def hasTime(s):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    s : string
        ISO 8601 formatted date / datetime string.

    Returns
    -------
    tuple, (bool, datetime.datetime).
        boolean will be True if input specifies a time, otherwise False.
    """
    try:
        return False, datetime.combine(date.fromisoformat(t), time.min)
    except ValueError:
        return True, datetime.fromisoformat(t)
        # do nothing else here; will raise an error if input can't be parsed

for t in ('2020-10-07', '2020-10-07T00:00:00', 'not-a-date'):
    print(t, hasTime(t))
    
# output:
# >>> 2020-10-07 (False, datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 7, 0, 0))
# >>> 2020-10-07T00:00:00 (True, datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 7, 0, 0))    
# >>> ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: 'not-a-date'
```

Comment: I think this will probably work, I could use dateutil in the except clause for my backwards compatibility issue.

Comment: I just want to note for anyone using python versions before 3.7 this backport gives you fromisoformat https://pypi.org/project/backports-datetime-fromisoformat/